# ITXEX field cleared when HR_INFOTYPE_OPERATION is called

Tags: abap, sap-hr

We got into difficulties in maintaining the `ITXEX` field (Long text indication) of an Infotype record.

Say we got an existing record in an `Infotype` database table with a long text filled (`ITXEX` field value in that record is set to `'X'`).

Some process updates the record through `HR_CONTROL_INFTY_OPERATION` like this:

```
CALL FUNCTION 'HR_CONTROL_INFTY_OPERATION'
  EXPORTING
   infty            = '0081'
   number           = '12345678'
   subtype          = '01'
   validityend      = '31.12.9999'
   validitybegin    = '19.05.2019'
   record           = ls_0081      " ( ITXEX = 'X' )
   operation        = 'MOD'
   tclas            = 'A'
   nocommit         = abap_true
  IMPORTING
    return          = ls_return.
```

This call does update the record but clearing it's `ITXEX` field.

It's important to say that making the same action through `PA30` does update the record and maintain `ITXEX` field as it was.

The described problem seems similar to [that question](https://answers.sap.com/questions/9959489/hrinfotypeoperation-fm-not-updating-infotype-value.html). Trying the solutions given there didn't solve the problem.

Why the two approaches (`PA30` and function module) don't work the same? How to fix this?

Comment: Doesn't this [blog post](https://blogs.sap.com/2013/04/30/update-long-text-in-infotypes/) answer your first question? (using `CL_HRPA_INFOTYPE_CONTAINER=>MODIFY_TEXT_TAB`)

Comment: Hi @SandraRossi, CL_HRPA_INFOTYPE_CONTAINER=>modify_text_tab is for updating the text. The text isn't cleared in our case, only the `ITXEX` indicator.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, FM parameters you use are incorrect. How do you want the infotype to be updated if you set `nocommit = TRUE`?

Also, you are missing the correct sequence which must be used for the update procedure:

1. Lock the Employee
2. Read the infotype
3. Update the infotype
4. Unlock the Employee

The correct snippet for your task would be

```
DATA: ls_return TYPE bapireturn1.
DATA: l_infty_tab TYPE TABLE OF p0002.
CALL FUNCTION 'HR_READ_INFOTYPE'
  EXPORTING
    pernr     = '00000302'
    infty     = '0002'
  TABLES
    infty_tab = l_infty_tab.

READ TABLE l_infty_tab ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<infotype>) INDEX 1.
<infotype>-midnm = 'Shicklgruber'. " updating the field of infotype

CALL FUNCTION 'ENQUEUE_EPPRELE'
  EXPORTING
    pernr = '00000302'
    infty = '0002'.

CALL FUNCTION 'HR_CONTROL_INFTY_OPERATION'
  EXPORTING
    infty         = <infotype>-infty
    number        = <infotype>-pernr
    subtype       = <infotype>-subty
    validityend   = <infotype>-endda
    validitybegin = <infotype>-begda
    record        = <infotype>
    operation     = 'MOD'
    tclas         = 'A'
  IMPORTING
    return        = ls_return.

CALL FUNCTION 'DEQUEUE_EPPRELE'
  EXPORTING
    pernr = '00000302'
    infty = '0002'.
```

This way `itxex` field is treated correctly and if existed on that record, will remain intact. However, this method will not work for updating the long text itself, for that you must use [object-oriented way](https://blogs.sap.com/2013/04/30/update-long-text-in-infotypes/), methods of class `CL_HRPA_INFOTYPE_CONTAINER`.

Comment: First, thanks for your reply after a long time. I fixed it, and will share if I get some spare time. However, it has nothing to do with locking nor commiting. 1. Who said we didn't lock? 2. Commiting can be done later.

Comment: Sorry but posting incomplete code will bring you with the incomplete answers. During the troubleshooting all the possible causes should be considered, I am not a telepath to guess what was done by you behind the scenes and what was not done